# Various shape drawing with CKEditor in drupal 7?

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there any way to draw various shapes (circle, triangle, rectangles) like MS-Office-Word/Paint shapes in the CKEditor. I tried to find the plugin, but could not. Is there anyway.